# .Net core connection string to MSSQL from OSX

Tags: sql-server, macos, asp.net-core

I am trying to connect to an MSSQL server from a C# ASP.Net core application running in OSX. The MSSQL is on a separate machine which firewall is configured to let connections via TCP to port 1433 and via UDP to port 1434.

The connection string I am using is:

`Server=IP\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DB_NAME;user id=****;password=*****`

What is very confusing at this point is that *the very same connection string works flawlessly* from Windows and both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. The moment I reboot in my OSX, then VS Code opens the project but raises the dreaded

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or 
instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection
to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is
configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, 
error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

exception. I have no idea what to do, as this code should work. What does the OSX implementation of the SQL Server connector do that is so different?

Comment: try adding port number at the end

Comment: @TheGameiswar, unfortunately I keep getting the same error.

I tried all combinations like: `IP,1433`, `IP,1434`, `IP\SQLEXPRESS,1433`, etc. that I can think of, but always with the same result...

Comment: Is this a string literal in the code? I had a similar issue once because I did not escape `\`. If this is not this I would start from making sure that you actually can connect to port 1433 on the target server (e.g. using telnet)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently the *nix implementation of the `UseSQLServer` method does not support instance names. Therefore `IP,port` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As Giuseppe said, you need to use IP,port. Named instances can run on various ports and Windows clients (i.e. SQL Management Studio) detects port by asking SQL Browser service.
In you case, you should open SQL Configuration Manager, Go to SQL Server Network Configution -> Protocols for SQLExpress (or whatever is name of the instance) -> TCP/IP (right click) -> Properties -> Ip Adresses tab, scroll to bottom and see (and/or) set the current port.

Comment: I *am* Giuseppe (both person asking and answering) :)